How to disable bluetooth in Android 13+?
 //Above android 12
            Button(onClick = {
                val intent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                activityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
            }) {
                Text(text = "Enable")
            }

This code helps me to enable bluetooth in Android 13+, but I don't know how to disable it
I have seen a REQUEST_DISABLE method and I tried this , but this is a private method so it doesn't   work
Button(onClick = { val intent = Intent(android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISABLE) activityResultLauncher.launch(intent) }) { Text(text = "disable") }

I would take your observation as a strong indication that this feature is simply not wanted. These days, many applications use Bluetooth at the same time (even the operating system), so if one application were to turn off Bluetooth, all the others would stop working too.

As Risto mentioned, and as you've seen from the BluetoothAdapter API documentation, the ability to programmatically disable Bluetooth has been deprecated and is no longer supported in newer versions of Android. This change is logical because Bluetooth is a system-wide feature, and disabling it from one app can negatively impact other apps, conflicting with the app sandboxing concept. This is similar to iOS, where apps also cannot programmatically disable Bluetooth.
The next best thing is to ask the user to manually disable Bluetooth. You can achieve this by the code below:-
Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings); 

This way, you respect the system's constraints and ensure that users can control their Bluetooth settings as needed.
You can find more information about this at the links below:-

How to open Bluetooth activity settings programmatically
Bluetooth adapter enable or disable not working
Bluetooth disable programmatically in Android


This doesn't work can you explain little elaborately.
I am getting this error
Unresolved reference: ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE

The constant BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE is hidden using @hide in the SDK, its value is "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISABLE". You may directly use "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISABLE" instead of BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE.
Use
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

to turn on Bluetooth
Intent intent = new Intent("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISABLE"); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISABLE_BT);

to turn off Bluetooth
Upon execution, a system dialog will prompt the user to turn on/off Bluetooth.
Once turned on/off onActivityResult() override method will be triggered.
In your case, you are using BluetoothAdapter.disable() try using the other method.

You cannot use the BluetoothAdapter.disable() method programmatically as it is not allowed by the Android system. Instead, you need to request the user to disable Bluetooth using an intent.
You can use the startActivityForResult() method with the ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE intent action to prompt the user to disable Bluetooth. This will display a system dialog asking the user to disable Bluetooth.
Intent disableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE);  
startActivityForResult(disableIntent, REQUEST_CODE_DISABLE_BLUETOOTH);

Note that you need to declare the BLUETOOTH_CONNECT and BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file to use Bluetooth features in your app.
It's also important to note that you cannot programmatically disable Bluetooth without user intervention in Android 13+, as it is a security restriction.

This doesn't work can you explain little elaborately.
I am getting this error
Unresolved reference: ACTION_REQUEST_DISABLE

The most elegant might be, to open the Bluetooth settings:
startActivity(Intent().setAction(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS))

And let the user flip the switch. There one can see the connected devices, which may be a keyboard, pen input, audio device and alike. It's certainly about connected devices, not to accidentally disconnect altogether; not necessarily other apps, which may use Bluetooth.
One can/should register a BroadcastReceiver for BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.
Alike this, the user can consciously switch it off and eventually disconnect all devices by doing so, while the application will be notified about what the user did. That's how it is supposed to work.
